# How to create random and Infinite walls with collision and a ball in libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm really new to Android Game Development but I have some experience with the standart Application Development.

What I want to create is a "TutorialGame" for learning purpose. The game is similar to this one: https://goo.gl/ywawt5 but instead of being a ninja the player is just a ball. And there are no enemies or anything else. It's just plain jumping from side to side wihtout any reason. As I said it's just for learning the code!

I started creating a little ball with LIBGDX's ShapeRenderer:

```
    shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
    shapeRenderer.circle(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 20);
    shapeRenderer.setColor(1,0,0,1);
    shapeRenderer.end();
```

The question ist now: Is this even the right way to start with something like this? I read about other classes in LIBGDX like circle and body but as there aren't really any tutorials on those and I'm a beginner I don't really know which class needs to be used here. Of course I will need infinite walls later on and both walls and ball should have collision (I think so?) but I don't really know how to do that.

I appreciate any answer to help me understand LIBGDX a bit more.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to break your problem down into smaller individual steps.

First, get your drawing working. You're correct to be using ShapeRenderer, and more info on how to use that class (and many other classes) can be found in [the libGDX API](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/) and [the libGDX wiki](https://github.com/libGDX/libGDX/wiki). Can you draw a circle in the center of the screen?

Once you have your drawing working, then worry about the animation. Can you make it so that circle bounces around the screen? You can use pretty basic if statements to figure out when the circle has touched the edge of a screen, and that same logic might be used to add a "wall" to each side of the screen. There really isn't a need for Box2D here.

Think about it this way: you don't actually need infinite walls, you just need to make it look like you do. You might do that by simply drawing the wall decorations on either side of the screen and moving them down a little bit each frame.

Since you asked about it, the [Circle](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Circle.html) class is simply a class that holds information about a circle: its location and its radius. That class also contains functions for testing whether a circle intersects with a circle, contains a point, etc. So you **can** use this class along with your other code, but you don't have to.

Similarly, the [CircleShape](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/CircleShape.html) class is another class that works with Box2D, the physics engine that comes with libGDX. Although you **might** use Box2D eventually, I definitely wouldn't recommend using it until you have the basics working.

Comment: Ok I understand what you mean with: "you don't actually need infinite walls (...)" should I move the Ball just by adding +1 to the X and Y values? And how do I tell Java to add +1 every second or whatever unit?

Comment: @r0d libGDX gives you a game loop that fires multiple times per second. Have you gone through the basic tutorials? If you're still a novice, you really might want to consider trying something like Processing instead of libGDX.

Comment: I do not agree with my downvote, and what you say "There really isn't a need for Box2D here."if it is true that you can do in many ways. but box2d offers, gravity, forces, collision ect, to drive the example objects for the player to jump from one place to another, and other things that may want in the future, and I say this why reinvent the wheel in this case, with the creation of your own, collision and physical?. It can be a little harder to learn, but the amount of options that gives you, I think it's worth, but it is just my opinion

Comment: @r0d That's not really in the spirit of StackOverflow, but I do have a forum available [here](http://forum.staticvoidgames.com/).

Comment: @KevinWorkman well I just have some minor questions I don't think they need a post in your forum. Would be rubbish there..

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question, I would use box2d, for walls and ball, here you have to start with box2d examples:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zDEQycnhaAc

on walls endless, I would try something like this

It depends on how you want to work, but if your player goes vertically, up or down, you can put a figure box2d, with the shape you want.
and get moving, shape for this area within the game
[image]

1. is the play area.
2. is the shape of box2d."example size"

for example, if your player up, you move your shape in that direction ect.

I never did, anything similar, I test this way, as first idea, I hope to help.

Note:
If you choose to use box2d, would not have to do a lot of simulations colliding bodies among themselves, also would have the gravity forces, only you would have to know how to use them, I think it would be easier in the end, but it is just my opinion